# Does Doctor Doofenschmirtz ever get back at bellhops?

Tags: phineas-and-ferb

In the *Phineas and Ferb* S1 episode “Tree to Get Ready”, Doctor Doofenschmirtz lists a lot of people he wants to take revenge on, besides his brother Roger and Perry the platypus.

[image: (Heinz showing illustration of meter maids and underwater welders.)]

> I bear lots of animosity to bellhops,
>   They never bring my luggage up on time
>   And taxi drivers really tax my patience,
>   If they vanished, would it really be a crime?
>
> I don't like meter maids or underwater welders,
>   Health fanatic cooks or camera crews!
>   Not fond of monks or yoga teachers,
>   Or sports fans in the bleachers!

Does Doctor Doofenschmirtz have a scheme targeting any of the people listed here any time in the show?

Comment: Looking over the full lyrics this appears to just be build up in the song to get to the point that he doesn't like a lot of people but the top of the pile is his "goody two-shoes brother".

Comment: If I remember right, Jamie Oliver (A "Health Fanatic Cook") shows up in an episode, but is not specifically targeted by Doof. Beyond that I don't recall anything specific about any of the other ones.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Certainly. His brother is Roger Doofenschmirtz, the major of Danville. Roger is a returning character, Heinz tries to get revenge on him in multiple episodes, not only this one. But In this question, I'm interested about the continuity of whether the other grudges ever appear, or Heinz just chooses other targets like hot dog vendors.

Comment: @b_jonas I understand I'm just pointing out that it could just be for the sake of the song only.

Comment: While it was not part of his evil plan, he does steal the *Bust Em!* camera crew's van in one episode. Does that count?

Answer (score 1):

I personally don't remember him getting "revenge" on other people that you listed in your question any time later in the show.
I think that ultimate point of this song is just to show that Dr. D hates those people.
In-Universe he probably got his "revenge" on them, but it was never shown on-screen. We can't judge, because we don't have enough information.